# How to set Authorization HTTP header in Guzzle?

Tags: php, http-headers, guzzle

I want to use API from Publons. They mentioned `"Any other requests should include a token in the Authorization HTTP header and prefixed with 'Token'.` So, i try to set the `Token` in headers. This is my code

```
$client = new Client([
            'base_uri' => "https://publons.com/api/v2/academic/",
            'headers' => [
                'Token' => "MyToken"
            ]
        ]);
```

The result is `{"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."}`. I make sure the token is correct, beacause I've try it on Talend API Tester and works. Can anyone help me? Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just guessing, there's not much in their docs but I suppose it would look like that:

```
$client = new Client([
            'base_uri' => "https://publons.com/api/v2/academic/",
            'headers' => [
                'Authorization' => "Token{Your api token here}"
            ]
]);
```

They want authorization header and token prefixed with "Token"...

Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36011790/guzzle-http-add-authorization-header-directly-into-request) question would give you more ideas how to deal with your case.

Comment: Its works, the key is `Authorizations` and value is `Token MyToken`